# p4 sync two labels without deleting the files in workspace

Tags: perforce

I have two labels and I need to get them one by one how could I get this labels without deleting the files in workspace using command line.

I find it hard to find solution because when I get the first label and then second the first label files were deleted. How could I kept those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sync specific parts of the workspace. Assuming they are in different directories, you can do:

```
p4 sync dir1/...@label1
p4 sync dir2/...@label2
```

If they are in the same directory, you can sync the files you care about individually.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
p4 sync @label1,label1
p4 sync @label2,label2
```

Using the rev range syntax keeps the `sync` operation from touching files that aren't in the label.

Caveat: if there are files that are absent from the label because they're deleted or were otherwise deliberately excluded, they'll persist in the workspace if they were there before you synced.